# Not getting token with acquireTokensilent but getting tokens with acquireTokenpopup Msal-browser

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api, msal-angular

I am updating MSAL version 1.x to MSAL-browser in angular.So I am trying to migrate from version 1.x
to 2.X.I was able to replace code successfully and it is working fine. but I am getting issue with acquireTokenSilent but its working fine by using acquireTokenPopup. I am following this link:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/v1-migration.md.
This is latest library published 11 days ago only and not much inputs i am able to get from internet other then basic documentation. The thing is when i am using acquireTokenSilent its giving error as:
***getTokenerror BrowserAuthError: no_account_error: No account object provided to acquireTokenSilent and no active account has been set***
but if i am using acquireTokenPopup at the same place, my application is working.
Sample:

```
public Tokenfunction(): void {
    this.MSALobject.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(response => {
       this.tokenSubject.next(response.idToken);
    })
    .catch((error: msal.AuthError) => {
      if (error) {
        return this.login();
      }
       somefunction();
      
    });
  }
```

but instead of acquireTokenSilent if i use acquireTokenPopup, its working fine i am not getting what is the issue.

Comment: `acquireTokenSilent` should be used with `acquireTokenPopup` or `acquireTokenRedirect` together. If you have signed in interactively, the user active account will be set and `acquireTokenSilent` can sign you in. If there is no user active account, you need to call `acquireTokenRedirect` or `acquireTokenPopup` to sign in interactively. See the sample code in the link you shared.

Comment: I have changed scopes parameter then it was working fine thanks and one question , i want to implement refresh token concept , what should be the approach.

Comment: A refresh token is automatically supplied when the `offline_access` scope is provided. `acquireTokenSilent` can handle the refresh token. Please see this part: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md#token-renewal. Let me know if there is anything unclear.

Comment: BTW, what changes did you make on `scopes` to make the code work?

Comment: I gave account object in my request. earlier was giving like this: request= {
    scopes: ['profile']
    
  };  but now i added one more line with my user account  as account : msalobj.getAllAccounts()[0]

Comment: I am adding offline_access to scopes and in the token object  returned from acquiretokensilent ,should we able to  see the refresh token along with access token and other info of the object?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you don't need to handle it by yourself because `acquireTokenSilent` can handle the refresh token.

Comment: ok thanks for your point, one more question, in console after one hour , would i be able to see new access tokens without refreshing in console as i am printing access token objects and suppose once it is expired do i would be able to see updated object?

Comment: Not sure about that. You can have a test in an hour to see what the result is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarize the comments into the answer in order to archive this question:

Giving account object in the request can resolve this issue.

Earlier was giving like this: `request= { scopes: ['profile'] }`; Add one more line with user account as account : `msalobj.getAllAccounts()[0]`.

I think you don't need to handle it by yourself because `acquireTokenSilent` can handle the refresh token.